# Java - Perform a cumulative sum using forEach or the Stream API

Tags: java, cumulative-sum

here my current code to perform a cumulative sum over a hash table Map< String,Double>

```
START.forEach((k,v)->{

            sum += v;
            END.put(k, sum);

        });
```

or, alternately,

```
END= START.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .collect(
                        Collectors.toMap(entry -> entry.getKey(), 
                                entry -> {
                                    sum += entry.getValue();
                                    return sum;
                                }));
```

But I have the following error:

```
Local variable sum defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final
```

How could I fix it?

I wouldn't want to use the standard for loop like that:

```
Iterator it = START.entrySet().iterator();
        double sum = 0;
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
            String key = (String) pair.getKey();
            Double value = (Double) pair.getValue();
            sum+=value;
            END.put(date, sum);
        }



START
------------
|first | 1 |
|second| 5 |
|third | 4 |

END
|first | 1  | 
|second| 6  |
|third | 10 |
```

Comment: Maybe `Double sum = map.values().stream().mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).sum();`?

Comment: @MincongHuang Sorry, I don't want the sum of all the map values. I edited the question by adding an example.

Comment: You want cumulative sum of double value??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Entries' order is important for cumulative sum.** If you're using `HashMap` as implementation, it makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time. So I recommend you to use another implementation, like `LinkedHashMap`. It use hash table and linked list implementation of the Map interface, with predictable iteration order.

```
Map<String, Double> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
map.put("first", 1.0);
map.put("second", 5.0);
map.put("third", 4.0);
```

**Use atomic reference to avoid "final" problem**. In Java, you can't use non-final variables in lambda as well as in anonymous inner classes. That's why you got the message *"Local variable sum defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final"*. Then, you can define the binary operator as `(x, y) -> x + y`, since you wish to summarize the current entry's value with the previous cumulative sum.

```
AtomicReference<Double> atomicSum = new AtomicReference<>(0.0);
map.entrySet().forEach(e -> e.setValue(
    atomicSum.accumulateAndGet(e.getValue(), (x, y) -> x + y)
));
```

---

Here's the final code.

```
Map<String, Double> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
map.put("first", 1.0);
map.put("second", 5.0);
map.put("third", 4.0);

AtomicReference<Double> atomicSum = new AtomicReference<>(0.0);
map.entrySet().forEach(e -> e.setValue(
    atomicSum.accumulateAndGet(e.getValue(), (x, y) -> x + y)
));

// tested in JUnit
assertEquals(10.0, atomicSum.get(), 0.0001);
assertEquals(1.0, map.get("first"), 0.0001);
assertEquals(6.0, map.get("second"), 0.0001);
assertEquals(10.0, map.get("third"), 0.0001);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `sum` to be an `AtomicLong` and perform `addAndGet` instead of the `+=` because, as the error said, you need sum to be final.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know but this snippet of code may help you.

```
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>();
ints.add(1);
ints.add(2);
ints.add(3);

AtomicInteger sum = new AtomicInteger(0);
ints.stream().sequential().mapToInt(sum::addAndGet).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Try to modify and use this code snippet in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [`java.util.concurrent.DoubleAdder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/DoubleAdder.html) and [`Collectors#toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) like this:

```
final Map<String, Double> START = new HashMap<>();
START.put("first", 1.0);
START.put("second", 5.0);
START.put("third", 4.0);

System.out.println(START.toString());

DoubleAdder sum = new DoubleAdder();
Map<String, Double> cumulativeSum = START.entrySet().stream().sequential().collect(
    Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, it -> { sum.add(it.getValue()); return sum.sum(); }));

System.out.println(cumulativeSum.toString());
```